# Get Foundation Zurb 5 to show French characters

Tags: character-encoding, zurb-foundation, typography, google-font-api

I am using Zurb Foundation and need to display some French paragraphs. I am using Lato Google Font which can display French characters properly. But currently I get for the following:
Boucherville est une ville dans la région de la Montérégie au Québec, Canada.
this appearing:
Boucherville est une ville dans la r�gion de la Mont�r�gie au Qu�bec, Canada.

Any insights on how to make sure French Latin characters appear properly in Foundation?

Here is the [website page](http://picsofcanada.com/bvilleqc.html)

Click on ***BouchervilleMap*** menu item to see the offending code

Comment: Could you post your markup ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your own personal CSS style sheet linked in your markup, could you post it please.

Based on what I can see in your mark up I think your problem is even though you are linking to the font in your  you don't ever tell the page Where or When to use it. All the CSS you link to are CDN's so they are obviously the standard templates which use other English characters.

What I do to override Foundation is I have a FoundationOverides.css which I call last in my  you could do the same and have something similar to this:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
body{
font-family: "Lato, Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  
}

button, .button {
font-family: "Lato, Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  
}
// And so on...
```

What I would advise is download a copy of Foundation.css open it in your Text editor and search for this line :

```
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Then just copy all the selector's one by one into your override CSS. Pain in the bum as it is mentioned 13 times but once you've done it, it's done.

Then in your html just make sure you include your override last like this:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Boucherville Quebec</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.7/slick.css"/>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.3.3/css/foundation.min.css" />
   <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.3.3/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>


   <link href="pathtoyour/css/FoundationOverride.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
```